# Building and Planning of a Web-Application

Tags: project-management, project-planning

Good morning everyone,

I hope I'm not posting this in the wrong place; I've been programming web projects, mostly in MVC and ASP.NET for consulting companies, but I always pick-up unfinished projects, so I gotta say, my experience in web development isn't as good as I'd like it to be. To improve my experience, I decided to accept building a project for a veterinarian clinic and I'm going to build the project in MVC.
There are a few things I'd like to know to make my project well structured and to avoid feeling lost in the process because I don't have as much time to research as I'd like to.
So the main questions I'd like to ask are:

- When beginning a new project, where
  should I begin? Making the
  stylesheets? Should I go straight for
  the code? If I make some planning,
  how should I go about it then?
- When building up the Media folder in 
  my project, if I decide I'll use
  jQuery and the like, what files
  should I really get? What's the best 
  way to implement jQuery in a MVC
  project without having to mention it 
  in every page?
- To make a sort of planning for
  myself, complete with deadlines I
  have to respect, what structure
  should I use?
- Well, I'm not good at designing at
  all, and I often have to rely on
  other people's CSS to make things
  look decent, so how could I use this 
  project to improve that and still
  make it look good?

I hope we can all share some experience in the matter at hand and make this topic help others who might be feeling the same weaknesses as I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Try to find a framework that suits your needs. If you want reusability, make sure you learn/understand the concept of the MVC pattern (OOP). I personally work with Zend-Framework which has a very big community.

  (However, a good practice is building your own framework. Look at other frameworks and learn about the pro's and cons.)
- Every project starts with an UML design: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language
- Don't try to invent the wheel again, for example: learn/play with the 960 css grid http://960.gs, jQuery and different database-types.
- Documentate everything!
- Test everything http://simpletest.org
- use subversion for easy access of previous versions of your project http://subversion.net
- book tip: [http://www.amazon.com/Communicating-Design-Developing-Documentation-Planning/dp/0321392353](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321392353)

When you start building your code I suggest you start with register, login and authentication. After that: Internationalization and localization (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization)

Then create your CRUD's and so on..

EDIT:
Some other resources you might wanna have a look at:

- [Requirements gathering](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735618798)
- [Planning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321392353)
- [Object-oriented design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008678) and [Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124)
- [Configuration management](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356158)
- [Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161622X) (or [Coding](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670))
- [Web design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356131) and [Usability](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321344758)
- [Documentation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137058268)
- [Software testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321369440)
- [Web application security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059600656X)

Good luck!!

Comment: Enrico, I'm very grateful that you're helping me find some orientation in the Web. I will look up everything you mentioned when I get home from work :)

Comment: :-) If PHP is not your thing you can also have a look at Django (Python) or Ruby on Rails (Ruby)

Comment: PHP is surely not my beach; I've been developing in ASP all along. As for server-side, I'm most comfortable with C#.